# How to mark current line in emacs with some background color?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

Is there a simply way to paint current line with some background color? Like it does `hl-lock-line-face-buffer` with regesp, but only the line wher point is.

**edit**:
It is not smth like HIGHLIGHT-CURRENT-LINE, bacause i need to mark a line, then another line, and move point everywhere without affecting that highlights.

Comment: No, i want the bg-painting to be kept after point moves to another line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [visible bookmarks (bm)](http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/bm) package will do what you want. I set `bm-highlight-style` to `bm-highlight-only-fringe` for a marker in the column only, but if you want the whole line coloured then set it to `bm-highlight-only-line`:

```
(setq bm-highlight-style 'bm-highlight-only-line)

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-f2>") 'bm-toggle)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'bm-next)
(global-set-key (kbd "<S-f2>") 'bm-previous)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) does what you are asking for. Use [`C-x p RET`](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc55) (by default) to set a bookmark at point. And you can configure the kind of [highlighting](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus#toc60) you want for such bookmarks.  This is similar to what `bm.el` offers (Ben's answer), but more flexible